# How to use theme_hook_suggestions()

Tags: 7, theming

I'm on page of my website and I'm viewing it with the theme developer module, which gives me a lot of information. It gives me some theme suggestions based on theme_hook_suggestions() which are:

```
html__profile_personal
html__profile_personal__%
html__profile_personal__113
html__profile_personal__edit
```

How can I create a new theme for this page?  What naming convention should I use, given the info above?

Comment: There is no such thing as a theme_hook_suggestions(), they are simply theme suggestions :) Are you sure that you really want to override html.tpl.php (which just contains the basic html tags) and not page.tpl.php, which contains the actual page content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the underscore with a hyphen, and you get the name for the template file.

If the suggestions you are getting are the ones reported by [theme_get_suggestions()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_get_suggestions/7), then they are the ones returned from [template_preprocess_html()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7) for a page at /profile_personal/113/edit.

The first suggestion would be applied for all the pages with a path starting with /profile_personal/; the last suggestion would be applied also for a page with path /profile_personal/edit, and the one before the last would be applied also for /profile_personal/113/revisions.

Whichever you choose, you should always check the path of the currently show page, via [arg()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7).